# GLPK: no primal feasible solution

Tags: algorithm, glpk

i m trying to solve a problem in GLPK, but it gives me this msg "problem has no primal feasible solution". Below you ll find the program. the constraint that gives me the error is the "constraint 6", but i don t know how can i fix it. tnx for ur help guys

```
param n, integer ; # nbr noeuds
param l, integer ; # Number of periods
param m, integer ; # nbr vehicle
set N := 0..n ; # set of nodes (plans & customers)
set Nc := 1..n ;
set T := 0..l ; # set of periods
set K := 1..m ; # vehicles
set A := {i in N, j in N : i!=j}; #Set of Arcs
# paramètres 
param u ; # unit produc. cost
param f ; # fixed produc. cost
param h{i in N},integer, >=0 ; # Holding cost
param c {i in N, j in N},integer, >=0 ; # Transportation cost
param C ; # Production capacity
param Q ; # Vehicle capacity
param L {i in N},integer, >=0 ; #Maximum or target inventory level at node i
param I0 {i in N},integer, >=0 ; # initial inventory at node i period 0
param d{i in N, t in T},integer, >=0  ; # demand
param M{t in T} := min( C, sum {j in T, i in Nc:j>=t } d[i,j] );
param Mx{i in Nc, t in T} := min( L[i], Q, sum {j in T:j>=t } d[i,j] );
# variables 
var p{t in T}, >=0, integer ; # production qty 
var q{i in N, t in T}, >=0, integer ; # qty delivered
var y{t in T}, binary ;# Setup for period t (1 if there is production at 
var x{i in N, j in N, t in T}, binary; # 1 if a vehicle travels directly from node i to j, 0 otherwise
var I{i in N, t in T}, integer, >=0 ;   # Inventory at node i, period t
var z0{t in T}, integer, >=0; # the number of vehicles leaving the plant in period t
var z {i in Nc, t in T}, binary;  # 1 if customer i is visited in t, 0 otherwise
var w {i in N, t in T}, integer, >=0  ;#load of vehicle before making a delivery
# fonction objectif: mimiser les coûts
minimize cost: sum{t in T:t>0} ( u*p[t]+ f*y[t] +(sum{i in N} h[i]*I[i,t] )+ 
(sum{ (i,j) in A} c[i,j]*x[i,j,t] )) ;


s.t. RInit{i in N}       : I0[i] = 0 ;
# Constraint (2)
s.t. R1{t in T:t>0}:I[0, t-1]+p[t]=sum{i in Nc}q[i,t]+I[0,t];
# Constraint (3)
s.t. R2{i in Nc, t in T:t>0} : I[i,t-1] + q[i,t] = d[i,t] + I[i,t] ;
# Constraint (4)
s.t. R3{t in T:t>0} : p[t] <= M[t]*y[t] ;
# Constraint (5)
s.t.R4{t in T:t>0} : I[0,t] <= L[0];
# Constraint (6)
s.t. R5{i in Nc, t in T:t>0} : I[i,t-1]+q[i,t] <= L[i];
# Constraint (7)
s.t. R6{i in Nc, t in T:t>0} : q[i,t] <= Mx[i,t]*z[i,t];
# Constraint (8)
s.t. R7{ i in Nc ,t in T:t>0}: (sum{j in N} x[j,i,t])=z[i,t];
# Constraint (9)
s.t. R8{i in N, t in T: t>0 and i>0} :sum{j in N}x[j,i,t]+sum{j in N} x[i,j,t]= 2*z[i,t];
# Constraint (10)
s.t. R9{t in T: t>0}: z0[t]<= m;
#Constraint (11)
s.t. R10{ t in T,(i,j) in A: t>0 and i>0}: w[i,t]-w[j,t]>=q[i,t]-Mx[i,t]*(1-x[i,j,t]);
#Constraint (12)
s.t. R11{i in Nc, t in T: t>0}:0 <= w[i,t] ;
s.t. R12{i in Nc, t in T: t>0}: w[i,t] <= Q*z[i,t];
#Constraint (13)
s.t. R13{i in N, t in T:t>0}: p[t] >=0;
s.t. R14{i in N, t in T:t>0} : I[i,t] >=0; 
s.t. R15{i in N, t in T:t>0} : q[i,t] >=0;
solve ;
printf "\n\nTotal cost:%f\n", cost ;
display Mx ;
display M ;
data;
param n := 3;
param l := 6 ;
param m := 1 ;
param u := 1 ;
param f := 10 ;
param C := 4;
param Q := 5;
param d : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 :=
          0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          1  0 5 6 7 8 9 10
          2  0 6 7 8 9 10 11 
          3  0 6 7 8 9 10 12 ;
param c : 0 1 2 3  :=
   0  0 0 0 0 
   1  5 6 7 8 
   2  6 7 8 9 
   3  6 7 8 9  ;
param h  :=
   0  4
   1  5
   2  6
   3  6  ;
param I0  :=
   0  0
   1  0
   2  0
   3  0  ;
param L  :=
   0  0
   1  1
   2  2
   3  3  ;
end ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is in your parametrization.

In Constraint 3:

```
s.t. R2{i in Nc, t in T:t>0} : I[i,t-1] + q[i,t] = d[i,t] + I[i,t];
```

You set I+q equals parameter d plus something. D is in the range 5 to 12 and all variables are positive.

In Constraint 6:

```
s.t. R5{i in Nc, t in T:t>0} : I[i,t-1]+q[i,t] <= L[i];
```

You limit the same I+q to be lesserequal the parameter L which just ranges from 1 to 3.
So I+q have to be greater than d (5) and lesser then L (1) which is infeasible.